# Unknown column error in full join syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, join

A friend and I were playing around with the `JOIN` clauses available in MySQL. Here is the table structure we have:

```
create table abc 
(
  c1 int,
  c2 char(1)
);
create table xyz
(
  c2 char(1),
  c3 varchar(5)
);
```

The values inserted into them are:

```
insert into abc
values
  (1,"a"),
  (2,"b");
insert into xyz
values
  ("a","apple"),
  ("c","car");
```

Now, I have the [following two SQL statements](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3b760/14) (sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3b760/14)):

```
select
  *,
  'full'
from abc
full join xyz
  using (c2);
```

and

```
select
  *,
  'full'
from abc
full join xyz
  on abc.c2 = xyz.c2;
```

As can be seen in the fiddle, the first query returns:

```
| C2 | C1 |    C3 | FULL |
|----|----|-------|------|
|  a |  1 | apple | full |
```

while, the second query raises and error:

```
Unknown column 'abc.c2' in 'on clause':
```

Why is the column `abc.c2` not recognised when using the `ON` clause of `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: When the heck did MySQL start allowing the FULL JOIN syntax? My experience is that FULL JOIN syntax is not supported.

Comment: I don't know why the first query even runs; as bluefeet pointed out mysql does not - afaik - support full outer joins. If you change the second query to left join or right join it runs without error. The more mysterious thing is why the first query, full join with using, actually runs.

Comment: This appears to be a bug specific to MySql: when your query is ran agains SQL Server ([demo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10a05/3)) or Oracle ([demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2a21/15)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it's not a bug mysql just doesn't support full outer joins. Both Oracle and SQL Server do support full outer joins. The "full" is being interpreted as a table alias as Rimas pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FULL JOIN` is not supported by MySQL. It's because `full` is recognized as alias to `abc` table. Try this query, it runs without errors:

```
select
  *,
  'full'
from abc
full join xyz
  on full.c2 = xyz.c2;
```

Comment: It's weird that FULL is not even a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) in current MySQL (5.7.x).