# Why is my column 'unknown' when using FULL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I'm learning sql and wanted to create my own tables to practise on. I found the following site: https://sqltest.net/

I created two tables to practise joins on. LEFT/RIGHT/INNER joins work fine with the sql statements i create but when i try to use FULL JOIN the following error appears:

Ouuuu snap '': Unknown column 'wizards.colours' in 'field list'

Is this something i'm doing wrong or a glitch with the website?

```
CREATE TABLE wizards
(
colours varchar(255),
numbers int,
symbols varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO wizards
VALUES ('red','49','£'),
       ('blue','83','$'),
       ('blue','72','£'),
('purple','24','%'),
       ('orange','82','$'),
       ('white','67',NULL),
('blue','17','%'),
       ('black','12','%'),
       ('green','97','&'),
('grey','1','%'),
       ('red','6','£'),
       ('red','76','%');

     CREATE TABLE warriors
(
colours varchar(255),
numbers int,
symbols varchar(255)
);  

INSERT INTO warriors
VALUES ('orange','59','£'),
       ('purple','2','£'),
       ('white','11','%'),
('blue','78','%'),
       ('grey','56','$'),
       ('red','5','%'),
('orange','92',NULL),
       ('green','50','$'),
       ('orange','49',NULL),
('red','1','%');
```

my sql statement:

```
SELECT wizards.colours, warriors.numbers, wizards.numbers
FROM wizards
FULL JOIN warriors ON wizards.colours=warriors.colours
ORDER BY wizards.colours;
```

Comment: Are you running this as and oracle query or a mysql query (mysql does not support FULL JOIN)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown column error in full join syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702405/unknown-column-error-in-full-join-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support `full join`:

[image]

You can use `left + union + right join`:

```sql
select * from (
    SELECT wizards.colours, warriors.numbers as warriors_numbers, wizards.numbers as wizards_numbers
    FROM wizards  
    LEFT JOIN warriors  ON wizards.colours=warriors.colours

    UNION

    SELECT wizards.colours, warriors.numbers as warriors_numbers, wizards.numbers as wizards_numbers
    FROM wizards  
    RIGHT JOIN warriors  ON wizards.colours=warriors.colours
) T
ORDER BY colours;
```

[Online demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8c5b1385219176f7135df79e07957d2d)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN`.  But, the `LEFT JOIN`/`RIGHT JOIN` hack *is not* the best way to implement it.  For instance, it doesn't handle duplicates correctly.

A better way is:

```
select cc.colours,
       wa.numbers, wi.numbers   -- whatever you want here
from ((select wi.colours 
       from wizards
      ) union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select wa.colours
       from warriors wa
      )
     ) c left join
     wizards wi
     on wi.colours = c.colours left join
     warriors wa
     on wa.colours = c.colours;
```

Even this is not 100% equivalent, because it does not handle `NULL` values correctly.  However, it usually gets the intention right.  You can fix the `NULL` handling by changing the `ON` conditions to use the `NULL`-safe comparison, `on (wi.colours <=> c.colours>`.

More importantly, you shouldn't need a `FULL JOIN`.  They are almost never needed in a properly formed database.

In this case, that would mean that you have a `colours` table with correctly formed foreign key constraints.  This is part of entity-relationship modeling and the right way to implement such relationships.